# gwt sending an object via post request

Tags: gwt, serialization, deserialization

I need to do a post request from a gwt app to a server. So far this works fine. However, originally I used an object that contained all the parameters send over to the server via a rpc request so I did not have to manage the serialization and deserialization myself. Now I send this stuff via a post request and on the server side I get something like username=blabla&location=blabla

I'd rather like to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
String serializedObject = parameterObject.serialize();
sendPostRequestWithContent(serializedObject);
```

and on the server side:

```
doPost(...)
    String serializedObject = request.getContent();
    ParameterObject parameterObject = ParameterObject.deserialize( serializedObject );
```

Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways.

1. For simple objects manually serialize and deserialize (field1=123123&field2=1232)
2. Use JSON as payload.

For solution 2 you can use a JSON parser on the beackend (Jackson, Gson, etc) and on the client you can either manually serialize the object to JSON or one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499831/how-to-genearte-json-on-the-client) methods.