# GWT - Serializing POST parameter in JSON before sending

Tags: java, json, gwt

I am trying to invoke a REST server from my GWT client. The server is not under my control and I am using GWT just for the client. The service expects to receive a JSON which is going to be deserialized with Jackson and mapped to a Java bean like this:

```
public DTO {
    String username;
    String password;
    /*...*/
}
```

Therefore, on my GWT project I created this class:

import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject;
import com.lh.clte.client.gui.util.CLTELabelProperties;

```
public class DTO extends JSONObject {
    String username;
    String password;
    /*...*/
}
```

And I am trying to send a POST request this way:

```
    DTO dto= new DTO();
    dto.setUsername(username);
    dto.setPassword(password);

    RequestBuilder b = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url);
    b.setHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    /***** ERROR *************/
    String data = dto.toString(); // JSONObject.toString(), no ovveriding
    /*************************/
    b.setRequestData(data);
    b.setCallback(new MyCallback<DTO>());
    try {
        b.send();
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, the toString method doesn't produce the expected JSON, but rather the string "{}". Where am I doing it wrong?
I also tried com.google.gwt.json.client.dev.JsonObject, but it doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: I do use GSON and it works, http://www.nooranibakerally.com/gson-a-library-to-convert-json-string-into-java-object-and-vice-versa/

Comment: And it works in GWT?

Comment: I am trying to use it in the client side (where I need to), but I get  "Unable to find 'com/google/gson/Gson.gwt.xml' on your classpath"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stringify your JSO object before sending over the wire:

```
String data = JsonUtils.stringify(dto);
```

This function is available in 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT, for 2.6.1 you have to create your own JSNI method

```
String data = stringify(dto);

private native String stringfy(JavaScriptObject jso) /*-{
  return JSON.stringify(obj);
}-*/;
```

Comment: I don't have a stringify method in my com.google.gwt.core.client.JsonUtils

Comment: Ok it's only in 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT, you have to use JSNI (edited my response with the jsni code). Although if you are going to use a lot json and request builder in your app, I would suggest to take a look to gwtquery library so as you would save a lot of code in your app,  ajax syntax is pretty easier and powerful, and databinding from json to pojo is very easy.

Comment: That didn't work for me. When stringifying, I get {"id":"75"} (or any other id) rather than the expected json. Also, if I try to stringify {"username":"myu","password":"myp"} I get the same output

Comment: I see, I thought your dto was extending `JavaSctiptObject` but it is a `JSONObject`, you have to unwrap it, modified my response.

Comment: I don't have the unwrap method in JavaScriptObject. I have it in JSONObject, but it is private

Comment: I am not unwrapping: I just switched my DTO to extend JavaScriptObject rather than JSONObject. Then it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`JSONObject` is a "map", it's not meant to be extended.

You could have your accessors store the value in an internal `JSONObject` rather than in fields, or you could use a `JavaScriptObject` with accessors written in JSNI and using `JsonUtils` for parsing and `JSONObject` for serialization (`new JSONObject(myJso).toString()`, pending GWT 2.7's `JsonUtils.stringify`), or you could use AutoBeans.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/10685489/116472 or [How to genearte JSON on the client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9499831/116472), among many others.

Answer (score 0):

If your backend uses Jackson, you should give [gwt-jackson](https://github.com/nmorel/gwt-jackson) a try.
You'll be able to use any DTO and even the server beans if you have access to the sources.

You declare your mapper like that :

```
public static interface DTOWriter extends ObjectWriter<DTO> {}
```

And then :

```
DTOWriter dtoWriter = GWT.create(DTOWriter.class);
String data = dtoWriter.write(dto);
```

BTW, shouldn't your Content-type header be `application/json` ?

Comment: Yes, I do use Jackson (implicitly, given the server is using Spring MVC for REST services. However, when I set up application/json, my server is not intercepting the request anymore and I am receiving an empty response

Comment: Also, even though I inherited com.github.nmorel.gwtjackson.GwtJackson and added jackson-annotations and jackson-databind along with gwtjackson into the buildpath, I get the following warning, which causes the compilation failure: Checking rule <generate-with class='com.github.nmorel.gwtjackson.rebind.ObjectMapperGenerator'/> [WARN] Unknown type 'com.github.nmorel.gwtjackson.client.ObjectWriter' specified in deferred binding rule

Comment: Are you using Maven ? You don't need jackson-databind but you need jackson-annotations and the source of jackson-annotations.

Comment: Still getting errors due to deferred binding at the instruction GWT.create(DTOWriter.class); DTOWriter is as you posted. I am not using Maven, but I am manually adding Jars to the project build path (and then copying them in the server classpath, as suggested by Eclipse as quick fix). The exception is: "Generator com.github.nmorel.gwtjackson.rebind.ObjectMapperGenerator threw an exception while rebinding 'com.lh.clte.client.dto.DTOWriter'
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4.

Comment: Remove the `extends JSONObject` from your DTO. You won't need it with gwt-jackson.

Comment: That's odd. I had the same error when I tested and removing JSONObject fixed the issue. Your DTO just contain the 2 properties and their getter/setter ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach will be to use RestyGWT (http://restygwt.fusesource.org/).

RestyGWT will take care of both serializing to/from JSON and also doing the POST request.

In your example, you will need a Class that defines which fields are serializable:

```
public class DTO {

    @Json(name = "username") // 'username' will be the name of the parameter in the json object
    private String username;
    @Json(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Then, you define the service by extending RestService

```
public interface DTORestService extends RestService {

    /**
     * Utility/Convenience class.
     * Use DTORestService.App.getInstance() to access static instance of DTORestService
     */
    public static class App {
        private static DTORestService ourInstance = null;

        public static DTORestService getInstance() {
            if (ourInstance == null) {
                Defaults.setServiceRoot(host); // the host from the 'url' you want the POST to be sent
                ourInstance = (DTORestService) GWT.create(DTORestService.class);
            }
            return ourInstance;
        }
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/dto.json") // the path from the 'url' you want the POST to be sent
    public void getDTO(DTO dto, // the json object you want to add to the post
                    MethodCallback<DTO> callback); // the method callback with any json result you will receive
}
```

Finally, you can call it by doing:

```
DTO dto = new DTO();
dto.setUsername(username);
dto.setPassword(password);
DTORestService.getInstance().getDTO(dto, new AMethodCallback<DTO>());
```

hope it helps