# GWT - JSONizing Class produces strange result

Tags: java, json, gwt

I want to jsonize some Objects for transferring. My Dummy class produces a totally different result than expected.
The output of the following code is  result={"id":3}:

```
package client;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class TestModul implements EntryPoint
{
  public void onModuleLoad()
  {
    Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
    dummy.setDummyText("test");
    String result = jsonDummy(dummy);
    System.out.println("result="+result);
  }

  public static final native String jsonDummy(Dummy dummy) /*-{

      console.log("JsonDummy:" + dummy)
      str = JSON.stringify(dummy);
      console.log("stringified:" + str)
      return str;
  }-*/;

  public class Dummy implements Serializable
  {
    String dummyText;

    public String getDummyText()
    {
      return dummyText;
    }

    public void setDummyText(String dummyText)
    {
      this.dummyText = dummyText;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
      return "Dummy{" +  "dummyText='" + dummyText + '\'' +     '}';
    }
  }
}
```

the console.log just gives me

```
JsonDummy:Dummy{dummyText='test'} 
stringified:{"id":3}
```

I set up a new standard GWT-Project for testing this. Using superdevelopment mode. I'm completely confused what's going wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: You should use `JavaScriptObjects` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499831/how-to-genearte-json-on-the-client

Comment: I don't want to use them because my model shall be completely independent of GWT and so the classes are just POJOS. So I need to do the jsonizing and transferinng manually.

Comment: OK, the way it is done in your link above results in doing everything completely manually... hmmm

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use POJO without depending on JavascriptObject or interface for AutoBean, you should use a library that will do the serialization for you.

Here is 2 that only do serialization/deserialization :

- [piriti](https://github.com/hpehl/piriti)
- [gwt-jackson](https://github.com/nmorel/gwt-jackson)

There is also [RestyGWT](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html#JSON_Encoder_Decoders). It is oriented REST but you can use its serialization mechanism.

I think [Errai](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/Marshalling) also has a mechanism but I never tried it.

Comment: Already tried jackson-mapper. Jackson-mapper needs annotating my model, which are POJOS. That means, they are no longer POJOS...
piriti seems not do JSONize classes? I need XML-Models, or?

Comment: I like FlexJson for Jsonizing. It works well on server-side. But FlexJson has no GWT Modul.

Comment: one more hint for gwt-jackson: If you don't use annotation it will still not work when the classes of the model are not in the  same package of the Mapper. SO it will still destroy the independency of the model.

Comment: Hmm what your model looks like ? Simple POJO with no annotation works in gwt-jackson. Even if it's in another package. You just have to be sure the package is included in your *.gwt.xml. If it is not, you won't be able to use the model class at all in GWT. If you use the TestModul you posted, you probably have to declare Dummy as static.

Answer (score 0):

The id=3 seems to represents some reference to the string, when I have more Strings, the ID changes.
I decided to do the JSONizing manually with

```
JSONObject someObject = new JSONObject(); 
...
someObject().stringify()
```

and as it is already answered in [How to genearte JSON on the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499831/how-to-genearte-json-on-the-client).
JSONizing-Frameworks for GWT need annotating my classes, that's not what I want. Cross-Site-Domain Communication seems to be not the best idea with GWT.

My tipp: When developing with GWT: Never get in need to use cross-domain-site requests an use RPC!...